# How do I horizontally align a picker input and action buttons in a Shiny app?

Tags: shiny

The following code creates and `h3` tab header, a picker input and 2 action buttons inside a class of `page-header`. The action buttons and slightly elevated compared to the picker input.  I would like to get the action buttons to be horizontally aligned with the picker input (see red boxes in the screenshot).
[image]

How can I adjust this code to make it work.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
    div(
      class = "page-header",
      
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 8,
          h3("Tab Header")
        ),
        
        column(
          width = 2,
          
          pickerInput(
            inputId = "picker", 
            label   = "Picker:", 
            choices = c("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3")
          )
        ),
        
        column(
          width = 2,
          
          actionButton(inputId = "apply_1",
                       label   = "Action 1",
                       icon    = icon("play")),
          
          actionButton(inputId = "reset_1",
                       label   = "Action 2",
                       icon    = icon("sync"))
        )
      )
    )
    
    
    
    
    
)
  


server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to horizontally align the `pickerInput` with the `actionButton`s would be to mimic the tag structure of the `pickerInput`, which looks like so:

```
<div>
    <label>...</label>
    <div>
    ....
    </div>
</div>
```

For the label I added an invisible label by setting the color to `transparent` but there are probably more elegant approaches.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(
    class = "page-header",
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 8,
        h3("Tab Header")
      ),
      column(
        width = 2,
        pickerInput(
          inputId = "picker",
          label   = "Picker:",
          choices = c("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3")
        )
      ),
      column(
        width = 2,
        tags$div(
          tags$label("Actions:", style="color: transparent"),
          tags$div(
            actionButton(
              inputId = "apply_1",
              label = "Action 1",
              icon = icon("play")
            ),
            actionButton(
              inputId = "reset_1",
              label = "Action 2",
              icon = icon("sync")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]